# Writing a flatMap function in Spark and Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, functional-programming, pyspark

I am trying to write flatMap function in python in a list comprehension way!

```
simpleRDD = sc.parallelize([2,3,4])
print(simpleRDD.map(lambda x:range(1, x)).collect())
```

and the output is this:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I have written Map function like this and it works, is it the correct way?

```
def myRange(x):
    return [x for x in range(1,x)]

def myMap(func, myList):
    return [func(i) for i in myList]

print(myMap(myRange, [2, 3, 4]))
```

But if I want write flatMap and achieve what the below code generates in spark, it wont work.

```
print(simpleRDD.flatMap(lambda x:range(1, x)).collect())
```

the output is:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

and this is my try which does not work.

```
def myRange(x):
    return [x for x in range(1,x)]

def myFlatMap(func, myList):
    return [*(func(i) for i in myList)]

print(myFlatMap(myRange , [2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension way to write a `flatMap` is to use a *nested for loop*:

```
[j for i in myList for j in func(i)]
#      ^outer loop     ^inner loop
```

Where the first loop is the outer loop that loops through `myList`, and the second loop is the inner loop that loops through the generated list / iterator by `func` and put each element in the result list as flattened.

```
def myFlatMap(func, myList):
    return [j for i in myList for j in func(i)]

myFlatMap(myRange, [2,3,4])
# [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, is this really what happens behind map and flatMap in spark? I mean the code in map function is the same as what we are trying to do?

Comment: I assume the spark implementation of `flatMap` is more complex than this list comprehension as it is distributed in nature. But the idea could be similar.

Comment: and my last question, why that unpacking (*) does not work properly here?

Comment: `*` unpack elements from the generator into the list but doesn't flatten it. Check these outputs `[*(1,2)], [*([1],2)]`. its basically just turns the inner generator as a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce:

```
flat_array = reduce((lambda arr1, arr2: arr1 + arr2), array_of_arrays)
```